# Failed loading opcache.so: opcache.so: cannot open shared object file

Tags: apache, debian, opcache

Ive got an issues with Opcache on my apache2 logs file

The error is : Failed loading opcache.so: opcache.so: cannot open shared object file

Do you have any ideas ?

I'm running on Debian squeeze php 5.4 with Opcache

Thanks

Comment: Any ideas ? OpCache is working but still get this issue

Answer (score 0):

OPcache is a *Zend* extension not a *PHP* one, and the [zend_extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend-extension) directive takes an **absolute path** of the opcache.so shareable image and not relative to the _extension_dir_.

As OPcache isn't bundled with PHP5.4, I assume that you've build OPcache with the PECL package, but however you've build it, you must use its absolute path for then Zend extension loader to find it.

Comment: Thanks but my path is the real one : zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/opcache.so

Comment: In which case your error is wrong.  5.4 reports the zend_extension argument literally so if it is as you say just "`opcache.so`" then that's the arg being set in the INI.  Check that you are loading the INI fileset that you thing you are being pathed in is -- e.g. change the arg to .../xopcache.so and see if the error also changes.  If not you are pulling in a different INI file.

Answer (score 0):

My environment was Windows 10x64 / WSL Ubuntu 20.04LTS / PHP 8.1

I tried to install Laravel

I did symbolic link for php8.1 instead of 8.2 because of Laravel requirements

The problem was in extension_dir path. I just changed it from "./" to /usr/lib/php/20210902

You should find your extension dir path by yourself with

`php-config --extension-dir`